# Is there a good index of pre-installed apps? If so, where is it?

Tags: processes

I have had a few errors on my phone that generate error messages that name the app that failed – but the error message dialog box names the failed app by process name, not by the app's common name.

To clarify with an example, I asked ["Unfortunately, the process com.sec.ims.android has stopped." What does this error message mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93029/unfortunately-the-process-com-sec-ims-android-has-stopped-what-does-this-err) a couple of days ago. The error message said that "com.sec.ims.android" was the process that failed, but that name doesn't make it very obvious that it's a pre-installed Samsung app, let alone indicate *what* pre-installed Samsung app it was.

So, is there some list that explains the process names like this?

```
"aaa.*" processes are native parts of Android.
"aaa.xxx.*" processes are native to a particular section of Android.
"mmm.*" processes are installed by this or that phone manufacturer.
"mmm.yyy.*" processes are parts of manufacturer app "yyy".
"ccc.*" processes are installed by this or that cellular carrier.
"ccc.zzz.*" processes are parts of carrier app "zzz".
And so forth.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These names are created by the developer. Some are by google, some by samsung, some by independent developers.

The may not necessarily have a "grouping" to them. Especially ones like "installed by carrier". The name is called a package name. There is no actual restriction of the package name, except there cannot be two packages with the same name.

To actually compile a list of all the packages, even just the ones installed by Android OS, would be massive, and not maintainable as they can, and likely will, have additions and removals with each release. Not to mention the additional packages that are created by other manufacturers for their hardware. Even different devices, that have essentially the same version of Android, from the same manufacturer, may have additional packages, or less packages.

In most cases, you may be able to tell what the package is for or who created it. But that may not always be the case. Take this package name. `com.facebook.katana` you can obviously tell it is made by facebook, but what is it? Well, it is the actual facebook app. And `com.amazon.venezia`, again, we can tell it is amazon, because they do follow the de facto standard, but they don't have to. This is the name of the package name for their app store.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that such a compilation would be too much to maintain. There are comparable lists for Windows, for example, which list every executable file name one might ever find running on a Windows machine, way back to things like print drivers for Word Perfect. If someone wanted to go to the effort, such a thing would exist. However, I take your reply to mean that no one _has_ gone to the effort to this point, which is still useful information.